# How to set props value as selected checked in dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a dropdown edit form where on edit user will able to see the option value as selected from `props` on edit. I tried with `defaultValue` and using `selected` but it seems my conditions are wrong.
Any suggestions which I can utilized to check the props value in option and display as selected on dropdown when user click edit.

Here `selectedPropsName` is what we are getting from `props` and I want to `map` and display this as selected.

Thanks...

**Code**

```
const results = [
    {
        'Name': 'apple',
        'description': 'apple is good for health'
    },
    {
        'Name': 'mango',
        'description': 'mango is very juicy'
    }
]

const props = {
    'Name': 'apple'
}

const CreateForm=()=> {
    const [spaceName, setSpaceName] = React.useState('');
    const [, setSpaceDescriptionName] = React.useState('');
    const handleChangeSpaceName = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setSpaceName(event.target.value);
        setSpaceDescriptionName(event.target.value)
    };
    const selectedPropsName = props.Name
    return (
        <>
            <div className='create-dropdown'>
                <TextField
                    className='create-textfield'
                    id='create-textfield'
                    select={true}
                    label='create Name'
                    value={spaceName}
                    onChange={handleChangeSpaceName}
                    SelectProps={{
                        native: true,
                    }}
                    variant='standard'
                    >
                    {results && results.length > 0 && results.map((optionNames:any) => (
                        <option key={optionNames.Name}
                        className='textfield-option'
                        value={`${optionNames.Name}, ${optionNames.description}`}>
                            {optionNames.Name}
                        </option>
                    ))}
                </TextField>
            </div>
            </>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you should be able to check if optionNames.Name equals selectedPropsName and then set the option's selected attribute to true, conditionally.

So,

```
 {results && results.length > 0 && results.map((optionNames:any) => (
                        <option key={optionNames.Name}
                        className='textfield-option'
                        value={`${optionNames.Name}, ${optionNames.description}`}>
                            {optionNames.Name}
                        </option>
                    ))}
```

becomes

```
 {results && results.length > 0 && results.map((optionNames:any) => (
                        <option key={optionNames.Name}
                        selected={optionNames.Name === selectedPropsName ? true : false}
                        className='textfield-option'
                        value={`${optionNames.Name}, ${optionNames.description}`}>
                            {optionNames.Name}
                        </option>
                    ))}
```

EDIT:

My mistake. I've taken another look. It looks like you are using Material-UI and so, the select component is controlled. You would have to set the initial value through the spaceName hook. And you would have to change the props.Name variable to include a "name, description" since that is what your option value={} field is expecting. So, these changes should make it work:

```
const props = {
  Name: "mango, mango is very juicy",
};
  const [spaceName, setSpaceName] = React.useState(props.Name);
```

Comment: Yes . You got me correct. I tried with this selected conditionally but I am always getting the first option value selcted only.

Comment: See the edited comment.

Comment: Thank you.. For your suggestion. It worked with a tweek in my case..